# Facebook access token not working in php

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, access-token

I take the access_token in my html page.

```
function fb_login() {    
FB.login(
    function(response){
    //etc....
    }, 
{scope:'email,user_about_me,user_activities,user_birthday,user_education_history, user_groups,user_hometown,user_likes,user_location,user_subscriptions,user_website, user_events,user_games_activity,user_status,friends_website,publish_actions, user_online_presence,publish_stream,offline_access,status_update,share_item, read_friendlists'}
);
```

}

Facebook Login...

after that, I want to publish stream with a php page. But this is impossible with access token error.

How to fix it? Why it isnt working?

Comment: did it work with just an email for example? Make it as simple as possible just to go through...

Answer (score 0):

See the example on github for [integrating Facebook JS SDK authorization with PHP SDK authoriziation](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/with_js_sdk.php).  Also make sure you are using the latest version of each SDK.